# Parse Json output from Nagios plugin

Tags: json, parsing, plugins, nagios

I've Searched this site and googled as much as i can but cannot seem to find a solution that works.

I have Nagios core running at home for a monitoring project. the status.dat is converted to a Json file on the web server using a plugin i installed.

the output from this plugin looks like this:

```
  {
  "programStatus": {
    "modified_host_attributes": "0",
    "modified_service_attributes": "0",
    "nagios_pid": "983",
    "daemon_mode": "1",
    "program_start": "1414556165",
    "last_log_rotation": "0",
    "enable_notifications": "1",
    "active_service_checks_enabled": "1",
    "passive_service_checks_enabled": "1",
    "active_host_checks_enabled": "1",
    "passive_host_checks_enabled": "1",
    "enable_event_handlers": "1",
    "obsess_over_services": "0",
    "obsess_over_hosts": "0",
    "check_service_freshness": "1",
    "check_host_freshness": "0",
    "enable_flap_detection": "1",
    "process_performance_data": "0",
    "global_host_event_handler": "",
    "global_service_event_handler": "",
    "next_comment_id": "1",
    "next_downtime_id": "1",
    "next_event_id": "77",
    "next_problem_id": "23",
    "next_notification_id": "304",
    "active_scheduled_host_check_stats": "1,5,5",
    "active_ondemand_host_check_stats": "0,0,0",
    "passive_host_check_stats": "0,0,0",
    "active_scheduled_service_check_stats": "3,11,11",
    "active_ondemand_service_check_stats": "0,0,0",
    "passive_service_check_stats": "0,0,0",
    "cached_host_check_stats": "0,0,0",
    "cached_service_check_stats": "0,0,0",
    "external_command_stats": "0,0,0",
    "parallel_host_check_stats": "1,5,5",
    "serial_host_check_stats": "0,0,0"
  },
  "hosts": {
   "localhost": {
      "host_name": "localhost",
      "modified_attributes": "0",
      "check_command": "check-host-alive",
      "check_period": "24x7",
      "notification_period": "workhours",
      "check_interval": "5.000000",
      "retry_interval": "1.000000",
      "event_handler": "",
      "has_been_checked": "1",
      "should_be_scheduled": "1",
      "check_execution_time": "4.007",
      "check_latency": "1.279",
      "check_type": "0",
      "current_state": "0",
      "last_hard_state": "0",
      "last_event_id": "0",
      "current_event_id": "0",
      "current_problem_id": "0",
      "last_problem_id": "0",
      "plugin_output": "PING OK - Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 0.08 ms",
      "long_plugin_output": "",
      "performance_data": "rta=0.076000ms;3000.000000;5000.000000;0.000000 pl=0%;80;100;0",
      "last_check": "1414556166",
      "next_check": "1414556470",
      "check_options": "0",
      "current_attempt": "1",
      "max_attempts": "10",
      "state_type": "1",
      "last_state_change": "1411951605",
      "last_hard_state_change": "1411951605",
      "last_time_up": "1414556170",
      "last_time_down": "0",
      "last_time_unreachable": "0",
      "last_notification": "0",
      "next_notification": "0",
      "no_more_notifications": "0",
      "current_notification_number": "0",
      "current_notification_id": "0",
      "notifications_enabled": "1",
      "problem_has_been_acknowledged": "0",
      "acknowledgement_type": "0",
      "active_checks_enabled": "1",
      "passive_checks_enabled": "1",
      "event_handler_enabled": "1",
      "flap_detection_enabled": "1",
      "process_performance_data": "1",
      "obsess": "1",
      "last_update": "1414556456",
      "is_flapping": "0",
      "percent_state_change": "0.00",
      "scheduled_downtime_depth": "0"
   },
   "test-vm": {
      "host_name": "test-vm",
      "modified_attributes": "0",
      "check_command": "check-host-alive",
      "check_period": "24x7",
      "notification_period": "workhours",
      "check_interval": "5.000000",
      "retry_interval": "1.000000",
      "event_handler": "",
      "has_been_checked": "1",
      "should_be_scheduled": "1",
      "check_execution_time": "3.001",
      "check_latency": "0.000",
      "check_type": "0",
      "current_state": "1",
      "last_hard_state": "1",
      "last_event_id": "70",
      "current_event_id": "72",
      "current_problem_id": "19",
      "last_problem_id": "10",
      "plugin_output": "CRITICAL - Host Unreachable (192.168.56.4)",
      "long_plugin_output": "",
      "performance_data": "",
      "last_check": "1414556437",
      "next_check": "1414556740",
      "check_options": "0",
      "current_attempt": "1",
      "max_attempts": "10",
      "state_type": "1",
      "last_state_change": "1413873683",
      "last_hard_state_change": "1413873683",
      "last_time_up": "1413873142",
      "last_time_down": "1414556440",
      "last_time_unreachable": "0",
      "last_notification": "1414556268",
      "next_notification": "1414563468",
      "no_more_notifications": "0",
      "current_notification_number": "2",
      "current_notification_id": "301",
      "notifications_enabled": "1",
      "problem_has_been_acknowledged": "0",
      "acknowledgement_type": "0",
      "active_checks_enabled": "1",
      "passive_checks_enabled": "1",
      "event_handler_enabled": "1",
      "flap_detection_enabled": "1",
      "process_performance_data": "1",
      "obsess": "1",
      "last_update": "1414556456",
      "is_flapping": "0",
      "percent_state_change": "0.00",
      "scheduled_downtime_depth": "0"
   },
   "winserver": {
      "host_name": "winserver",
      "modified_attributes": "0",
      "check_command": "check-host-alive",
      "check_period": "24x7",
      "notification_period": "24x7",
      "check_interval": "5.000000",
      "retry_interval": "1.000000",
      "event_handler": "",
      "has_been_checked": "1",
      "should_be_scheduled": "1",
      "check_execution_time": "4.004",
      "check_latency": "0.000",
      "check_type": "0",
      "current_state": "0",
      "last_hard_state": "0",
      "last_event_id": "75",
      "current_event_id": "76",
      "current_problem_id": "0",
      "last_problem_id": "20",
      "plugin_output": "PING OK - Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 0.44 ms",
      "long_plugin_output": "",
      "performance_data": "rta=0.438000ms;3000.000000;5000.000000;0.000000 pl=0%;80;100;0",
      "last_check": "1414556380",
      "next_check": "1414556684",
      "check_options": "0",
      "current_attempt": "1",
      "max_attempts": "10",
      "state_type": "1",
      "last_state_change": "1414556303",
      "last_hard_state_change": "1414556303",
      "last_time_up": "1414556384",
      "last_time_down": "1414556303",
      "last_time_unreachable": "0",
      "last_notification": "1414556303",
      "next_notification": "1414558103",
      "no_more_notifications": "0",
      "current_notification_number": "0",
      "current_notification_id": "302",
      "notifications_enabled": "1",
      "problem_has_been_acknowledged": "0",
      "acknowledgement_type": "0",
      "active_checks_enabled": "1",
      "passive_checks_enabled": "1",
      "event_handler_enabled": "1",
      "flap_detection_enabled": "1",
      "process_performance_data": "1",
      "obsess": "1",
      "last_update": "1414556456",
      "is_flapping": "0",
      "percent_state_change": "5.99",
      "scheduled_downtime_depth": "0"
   }
  },
```

and goes on forever with host infomation.

now ive managed to parse this using rainmeter web parser and a regex helper called rainregex quite easily.

what i would like to do is use this information on a web page.

i've tried doing jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>

<script>
$.getJSON("http://<serverIP>/nagios/statusJson.php", function( data){ 
 var items = [];
$.each( data, function( key, val ) {
items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
});

 $( "<ul/>", {
"class": "my-new-list",
html: items.join( "" )
}).appendTo( "body" );
});
</script>

        </script>
```

but i couldn't get it to pull the information from the php file.

im not sure what im doing wrong here.

Comment: Where is the PHP file you mentioned?

Comment: sorry i forgot to change the code

$.getJSON("http://<serverIP>/nagios/statusJson.php", function( data){

ideally i would like to do:
 $.getJSON("http://<username>:password@<serverIP>/nagios/statusJson.php", function( data){

but im not sure if its supported

@Raptor

Answer (score 1):

In case you were still curious about a solution, this might help you:

1. If you were pulling from the php file, you have to make sure that you echo the json encoded array you created:

echo json_encode($postData);

2. You can also skip parsing using php, and get the info straight from the Nagios RESTful API(I assume you have the api plugin installed as well). From there you can parse and output the json using your jquery script.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I Managed to Resolve this issue myself.

I'm not fluent enough in JQuery so i decided to use a Python Script to parse the Json Data and update it to a SQL Table, from here i was able to easily use PHP to query the SQL DB for the data.

Thank you all anyway. ill edit this comment soon when i'm finished polishing the script.